# How to deserialize below json data into collection list using jackson?

Tags: json, jackson

```
{
    "TOTALRECORDCOUNT": 588,
    "RECORDCOUNT": 588,
    "HASMORE": false,
    "RECORDSET": {
        "COLUMNS": [
            "PARTNERSEGMENTID",
            "ORGANIZATIONID",
            "ORGANIZATIONNAME",
            "PROGRAMTRACK",
            "PARTNERLEVEL"
        ],
        "DATA": [
            [
                "Partner_Segment_GES",
                1,
                "Relayware",
                "ProgramTrack_SolutionPartner",
                "AuthorizedLevel"
            ],
            [
                "Partner_Segment_GES",
                2,
                "Tata Communications",
                "ProgramTrack_SolutionPartner",
                null
            ],
```

Comment: The json you have posted is not a valid one. Please provide the entire correct json.

Comment: Thaks for replay. correct json is   {
    "RECORDSET": {
        "COLUMNS": [
            "MEMBERSHIPLEVEL",
            "PARTNERSEGMENTID",
            "ORGANIZATIONID",
            "ORGANIZATIONNAME",
            "PROGRAMTRACK",
            "CREATED"
        ],
        "DATA": [
            [
                "ProgramLevel_Premier",
                "Partner_Segment_GES",
                2,
                "Tata Communications",
                "ProgramTrack_SolutionPartner",
                "2008-06-10T20:03:07Z"
            ]
        ]
    }
}

Comment: I have posted an answer below. For future please add more details and sample code that you have tried and the problem you are getting in the code.Also Please correct the question when asked in the comments. Happy Learning!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use jackson `@JsonRootName` annotation as the json you have posted has only one top level key. If there are more you can create a pojo with recordSet being a field of that.

1. Case when json only has recordSet as the toplevel key:
   Here is the code: Pojo for recordSet

   ```
   @JsonRootName("RECORDSET")
   class RecordSet{

      @JsonProperty("DATA")
      List<List<String>> data;

      @JsonProperty("COLUMNS")
      List<String> columns;

      //getter and setter
   }
   ```

Code to deserialize json to RecordSet object

```
String jsonString="{ \"RECORDSET\": { \"COLUMNS\": [ \"MEMBERSHIPLEVEL\", \"PARTNERSEGMENTID\", \"ORGANIZATIONID\", \"ORGANIZATIONNAME\", \"PROGRAMTRACK\", \"CREATED\" ], \"DATA\": [ [ \"ProgramLevel_Premier\", \"Partner_Segment_GES\", 2, \"Tata Communications\", \"ProgramTrack_SolutionPartner\", \"2008-06-10T20:03:07Z\" ] ] } }";

        ObjectMapper mapper=new ObjectMapper();
        mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.UNWRAP_ROOT_VALUE, true);

        RecordSet recordSet = mapper.readValue(jsonString, RecordSet.class);

       //The below two statements can be replaced with the logic that you want to operate on deserialized object
        System.out.println(recordSet.getColumns());
        System.out.println(recordSet.getData());
```

2. Case when totalRecordSetCount and other fields are part of top level json:

   ```
   class Response{

      @JsonProperty("HASMORE")
      private boolean hasMore;

      @JsonProperty("RECORDCOUNT")
      private int recordCount;

      @JsonProperty("TOTALRECORDCOUNT")
      private int totalRecordCount;

      @JsonProperty("RECORDSET")
      RecordSet recordSet;

     //getter and setter
   }
   ```

Take the RecordSet pojo from case#1

Code to deserialize:

```
  ObjectMapper mapper=new ObjectMapper();
            Response response = mapper.readValue(jsonString, Response.class);

            RecordSet recordSet = response.getRecordSet();


 //The below two statements can be replaced with the 
 //logic that you want to operate on deserialized object

            System.out.println(recordSet.getColumns());
            System.out.println(recordSet.getData());
```

Comment: Once again Thanks for solution but  my part of json DATA": [ [ "Partner_Segment_GES", 1, "Relayware", "ProgramTrack_SolutionPartner", "AuthorizedLevel" ], [ "Partner_Segment_GES", 2, "Tata Communications", "ProgramTrack_SolutionPartner", null ] ] does not have filednames .I want to map each array to object directly instead of getting as string array.i don't want iterate all list arrays and creating objects again.can't we map above data to objects directly?  like below  Class Data{ private String segemt,private String track,private String id}

Comment: According to standard json object mapping , you can not do that. though you can iterate over and populate the fields manually in a for each loop. I would suggest not to do that because relying on the order of data in a list and populating an objects variable from that is not a good idea. You should rethink about the structure of json inside "DATA". instead of a list of string it should be a list of map. inside the map you can have keys as object variable and values as current values.